# pivotUtilities Unfedined

Tags: reactjs, pivot-table

I want to create my own aggregator but i am not able to access pivotUtilities as it says undefined.
All i want is to hide certain aggrigators from the dropdown and add one custom one which is my own. i am using https://github.com/plotly/react-pivottable#readme for this
My component is like this:

```
  import React, {Component} from 'react';
  import $ from 'jquery';
  import PivotTableUI from 'react-pivottable/PivotTableUI';
  import 'react-pivottable/pivottable.css';
  import TableRenderers from 'react-pivottable/TableRenderers';
  import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';
  import createPlotlyRenderers from 'react-pivottable/PlotlyRenderers';

  import { Data } from './constants/DataConstants'
  const PlotlyRenderers = createPlotlyRenderers(Plot);

  class Pivottable extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = props;
    }

    SumOverCount(attributeArray){
      console.log(attributeArray)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      console.log('renderers:', $.pivotUtilities);

    }

    render() {
      const tableData = Data
      // console.log('renderers:', $.pivotUtilities);
      return (
        <div>
          <PivotTableUI
            data={tableData}
            // aggregators={{Sum: function() { return this.SumOverCount() } }}
            onChange={s => this.setState(s)}
            renderers={Object.assign({}, TableRenderers, PlotlyRenderers)}
            {...this.state}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  export default Pivottable;
```

Comment: DO u have solution for this please post

Answer (score 0):

You may need to import jquery first if I understand correctly.